# how to cast string to a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I didn't find the keyword for google...

My Problem is

let's have a json array

```
{
  "a":"b",
  "c" : "d",
  "api" : 
  {
    "name":"listOfNetwork",
    "param" :['xyz','xyz1']
  } 
}
```

Now i have a javascript method

```
function listOfNetwork(param1, param2) //name-of-api, params
{
     // do something.
}
```

how to invoke this function by retrieving the name and parameters from JSON.

Please help

Comment: Assuming that the JSON array is called `myJSON`, you could get the values from the array by calling `myJSON.api.name`, `myJSON.api.param[0]`, etc. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
window[json.api.name].apply(this, json.api.param)
```

Thats all.